# How we Access datagrid header checkbox

Tags: apache-flex

i am facing problem to access the datagrid header check box. i added a check box in a column with the help of headeritemrender,how i can access that check box.

Thanks

Atul Yadav

Comment: this might help: http://blogs.adobe.com/aharui/2010/01/checkboxes_in_datagrid_with_ch.html